# Android requests taking around 40 secs to get the response from the server?

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit

In my android app, I am using `retrofit` with `okhttp` for making requests to my server, currently some of the api's which I call **only** in the beginning of my app takes `40 secs`(when network speed is slow) but when I hit same api's from `Postman tool` on desktop or on any online tool e.g `https://client.restlet.com/` it takes normal (100-200) ms, I have also tried HttpUrlConnection and other libraries and the time taken is same so I think there is no error from android side code.

I have also logged requests on the server which is in NodeJs and the thing is server is getting requests after 40 secs which mean these 40 secs are getting wasted where?

Can anyone Please tell me what can be possible ways this problem is occuring, I would really appreciate it, Please help me.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question with `when network speed is slow`?

Comment: @tyczj I am connected to the same network on the desktop but there how can it work perfectly fine everytime?

Comment: If your device has a poor network connection there is nothing you can do same network or not, if you are sitting right next to the router and you still have a "slow connection" then it sounds like you have a device problem

Comment: @tyczj But on that same device other android apps are not lagging that much, very little? .

Comment: @tyczj Then why when I am calling same api again on android then it is taking so much less time, and it is happening every time whenever I make first requests it only hangs there after that everytime I get response in around 400 ms?